# UPDATE or MERGE INTO or maybe anything else

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am using Oracle PL/SQL.
I have table A:

```
ID  SALES
--------
1   5
2   3
3   231
2   1
3   421
1   2
```

Table B:

```
ID  REGION
------------
1   London
2   New-York
3   Paris
4   Dublin
5   Munich
```

and table C:

```
ID  REGION
------------
1   London
2   New-York
```

Also i have table D:

```
ID  SUM_OF_SALES
------------
1   .
2   .
3   .
```

The task is to fill value SUM_OF_SALES in table D with the sum of column sales in table A grouped by ID column where A.ID = B.ID and B.REGION = C.REGION. The result i want is:

```
ID  SUM_OF_SALES
------------
1   7
2   4
3   .
```

I would be very appreciated for different approaches to this task.

Comment: Do you really need a physical table? You may want to consider a view, then you don't even need to update. Just a thought.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
MERGE INTO  d
USING (SELECT a.id, SUM(a.sales) sum_of_sales
       FROM   a,b,c
       WHERE  a.id = b.id
       AND    b.region = c.region
       GROUP BY a.id) q
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET d.sum_of_sales = q.sum_of_sales
```